# Can't draw electric field dipole

Tags: maxima

I am trying to simulate electric field dipole by using Maxima.
Here is the code:

```
P : 1$
eps0 : 8.854$
Ex : 3*P*y*x/(4*π*eps0*(x^2 + y^2)^2.5)$
Ey : P*(3*y^2/(x^2 + y^2) + 1)/(x^2 + y^2)^1.5/(4*π*eps0)$
ew : sqrt(Ex^2 + Ey^2)$

contour_plot (ew,[x, -4, 4], [y, -4,4]);
```

But i am getting only straight lines.
What can be wrong, because similar code in Wolfram Mathematica works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contour_plot` is not as smart as the corresponding function in Mathematica. You can help it a bit.

```
P : 1$
eps0 : 8.854$
Ex : 3*P*y*x/(4*%pi*eps0*(x^2 + y^2)^2.5)$
Ey : P*(3*y^2/(x^2 + y^2) + 1)/(x^2 + y^2)^1.5/(4*%pi*eps0)$
ew : sqrt(Ex^2 + Ey^2)$

BIG: subst([x=1/4, y=1/4], ew)$
cap_log(e, c):= if e > c then log(c) else log(e)$

set_plot_option ([gnuplot_preamble, "set cntrparam levels 8"])$
contour_plot ('cap_log(ew, BIG), [x, -4, 4], [y, -4, 4])$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plotdf.

```
(%i1) [P,eps0] : [1,8.854]$
(%i2) Ex : 3*P*y*x/(4*%pi*eps0*(x^2 + y^2)^2.5)$
(%i3) Ey : P*(3*y^2/(x^2 + y^2) + 1)/(x^2 + y^2)^1.5/(4*%pi*eps0)$
(%i4) plotdf([Ex,Ey],[vectors,"blank"]);
```

Click on some points in the plot, then enter the Plot Setup menu (the icon with a wrench and a screw driver), erase the color "red" in fieldlines and choose a color, for instance "blue", in curves. Return to the plot by clicking in Ok, and click again in the plot to trace a few equipotential curves.